# IdentityServer4 ConfigurationDbContext not loading client secrets

Tags: entity-framework, identityserver4, eager-loading

I want to display a list of clients and their secrets in an admin-only page of an MVC app baked into my IdentityServer project that is using EntityFramework.

I currently have a reference to `ConfigurationDbContext` in my controller from dependency injection and can access the client details. However, the `ClientSecrets` property of each client returned from the context does not have the secrets loaded, and is set to null. How can I force the context to load the ClientSecrets, which are stored in another table? Is there a different way I should be doing this?

Comment: Probably you'll need to call `Include`.. See [Entity Framework Loading Related Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 0):

Because the entity framework saved the client secrets in the separate table you have to use the entity framework's extension method - **Include**.

```
public class ApplicatonsService : IApplicationsService
{
    private readonly ConfigurationDbContext is4Context;

    public ApplicatonsService(ConfigurationDbContext is4Context)
    {
        this.is4Context = is4Context;
    }

    public Task<List<Client>> GetApplicationsAsync()
    {
        return Task.FromResult(is4Context.Clients
                .Include(c => c.ClientSecrets)
                .Select(c => c.ToModel()).ToList());
    }
    ...

}
```